# WSO2 EI Apply Patch to version 6.1.1

Tags: wso2-esb

I would like to apply this patch to WSO2 EI 6.1.1: https://github.com/wso2/product-ei/issues/780

How can I do this?

I tried building wso2-synapse-release-2.1.7-wso2v14 and ended up with the jars named like synapse-nhttp-transport-2.1.7-wso2v15-SNAPSHOT.jar.

I then create a patch directory with these jars and restart the server and it applies the jars but i get both the old version and the new version in the components/plugins directory (synapse-nhttp-transport_2.1.7.wso2v15.jar and synapse-nhttp-transport-2.1.7-wso2v15-SNAPSHOT.jar).

Comment: I think that you can use wso2 WUM (http://wso2.com/wum) as far as I know you can then get an "already patched" version of 6.1.1

Comment: you can as well get the latest updates from here : https://github.com/wso2/product-ei/releases